# Unboxing Values Types from Objects

Tags: c#, .net, clr, unboxing

I've been trying to understand this paragraph, but somehow I couldn't virtualize it in my mind, some one please elaborate it little bit:

> Unboxing is not the exact opposite of boxing. The unboxing operation
>   is much less costly than boxing. Unboxing is really just the operation
>   of obtaining a pointer to the raw value type (data fields) contained
>   within an object. In effect, the pointer refers to the unboxed portion
>   in the boxed instance. So, unlike boxing, unboxing doesn't involve the
>   copying of any bytes in memory. Having made this important
>   clarification, it is important to note that an unboxing operation is
>   typically followed by copying the fields.
>
> Richter, Jeffrey (2010-02-05). CLR via C# (Kindle Locations
>   4167-4171). OReilly Media - A. Kindle Edition.

Comment: had exactly the same question when reading to the paragraph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to box an int you need to create an object on the heap large enough to hold all of the data that the struct holds.  Allocating a new object on the heap means work for the GC to find a spot, and work for the GC to clean it up/move it around during and after its lifetime.  These operations, while not *super* expensive, aren't cheap either.

To unbox a value type all you're doing is de-reference the pointer, so to speak.  You simply need to look at the reference (which is what the `object` you have is) to find the location of the actual values.  Looking up a value in memory is very cheap, which is why that paragraph is saying 'unboxing' is cheap.

***Update:***

While an unboxed value type will usually be copied to some other location right after being unboxed, that isn't always the case.  Consider the following example:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
  private int value = 42;
  public void Foo()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(value);
  }
}

static void Main()
{
  object obj = new MyStruct();
  ((MyStruct)obj).Foo();
}
```

The `MyStruct` is boxed into `obj` but when it's unboxed it's never copied anywhere, a method is simply invoked on it.  LIkewise you could pull a property/field out of the struct and copy just that part of it without needing to copy the whole thing.  This might look a bit contrived, but it's still not entirely absurd.  That said, as your quote implies, it's still likely to copy the struct after you unbox it.

Comment: But after it finds the values, the values will be copied back to Stack, is that correct?

Comment: @Braveyard No, that's not.  It's rather common that once the value is unboxed it will be copied, but it doesn't need to be.  Additionally it may not be copied back to the stack, it could be copied to a field of some other reference type on the heap.

Comment: What if you call `((MyStruct)obj).value`, is the value be copied to stack again?

Comment: Well in that case `value` is private, so it wouldn't compile ;)  No, it wouldn't copy the whole MyStruct to the stack, it would just copy `value` into whatever you pass/assign it to.  If you unbox the MyStruct and either assign it to a MyStruct variable (or a field of something else of type MyStruct), or pass it into a method that takes a MyStruct, then you'll be performing a copy.

Comment: I compiled (after correcting error with field initializer) your sample code in Visual Studio 2010 and when I use Reflector to look at generated IL, unboxed MyStruct IS ACTUALLY COPIED to temporary local variable before Foo() is called on it. Any idea why?

Comment: @Nuf: You may be right, since in the last statement OP did, actually values are copied to temporarily stack and does the work on that area instead of heap.

Comment: @Servy regarding the 'copy back to stack' did your result really performed the method on heap, or Nuf said is correct ?